# Successful installation of Superset (3.0.0) on Ubuntu 22.04.3, but failed to log in

Tags: installation, apache-superset

I attempted to install Superset (3.0.0) on Ubuntu Server 22.04.3 from scratch using this guide https://superset.apache.org/docs/installation/installing-superset-from-scratch, and I can't say that it was successful.

Here is what I did step by step:

1. `sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev python3-dev python3-pip libsasl2-dev libldap2-dev default-libmysqlclient-dev`  - SUCCESS.
2. `pip install --upgrade setuptools pip` - SUCCESS.
3. `pip install virtualenv` - SUCCESS, but with warning "The script virtualenv is installed in '/home/superset/.local/bin' which is not on PATH".
4. `python3 -m venv venv . venv/bin/activate`
   Here I got **error** "The virtual environment was not created successfully because ensurepip is not available.  On Debian/Ubuntu systems, you need to install the python3-venv package using the following command: apt install python3.10-venv".
5. `apt install python3.10-venv` - SUCCESS.
6. `python3 -m venv venv . venv/bin/activate`
   SUCCESS.
7. `pip install apache-superset` - SUCCESS.
8. `superset db upgrade` - **ERROR**: "Error: Could not locate a Flask application. Use the 'flask --app' option, 'FLASK_APP' environment variable, or a 'wsgi.py' or 'app.py' file in the current directory". Before applying this command, you should set the environment variable 'export FLASK_APP=superset'.
9. `export FLASK_APP=superset` - SUCCESS.
10. `superset db upgrade` - **ERROR**: "A Default SECRET_KEY was detected, please use superset_config.py to override it.". But it doesn't work. As I understood еhe SECRET_KEY is read from the environment variable. Ok, apply next steps.
11. `openssl rand -base64 42` - SUCCESS.
12. `export SUPERSET_SECRET_KEY= the previously generated key` - SUCCESS.
13. `superset db upgrade` - SUCCESS.
14. `superset fab create-admin` - I received a warning 'No PIL installation found,' but proceeded successfully with the admin user creation process.
15. `superset load_examples` - I received a warning "No PIL installation found" but proceeded successfully.
16. `superset init` -  I received a warning "No PIL installation found" but proceeded successfully.
17. `cd superset-frontend`
    `npm ci`
    `npm run build`
    `cd ..`
    I attempted to locate the 'superset-frontend' directory, but I was unsuccessful, so I skipped this step.
18. `superset run -h 0.0.0.0 -p 8088 --with-threads --reload --debugger`
    Here I added '-h 0.0.0.0' to the default command - SUCCESS.
19. `http://192.168.10.12:8088/login/` - SUCCESS, the login page was displayed.
20. I entered my login and password, pressed Enter, and... I was redirected to the login page again. I checked the console and found an **error**:
    `"GET /login/ HTTP/1.1" 200 - 2023-10-09 11:30:15,676:INFO:flask_wtf.csrf:The CSRF session token is missing. Refresh CSRF token error Traceback (most recent call last): File "/home/superset/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask_wtf/csrf.py", line 261, in protect validate_csrf(self._get_csrf_token()) File "/home/superset/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask_wtf/csrf.py", line 103, in validate_csrf raise ValidationError("The CSRF session token is missing.") wtforms.validators.ValidationError: The CSRF session token is missing.`
21. Ok,  I stopped the Superset server, opened the /home/superset/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/superset/config.py file, and changed WTF_CSRF_ENABLED from True to False.
22. Started the server again with command `superset run -h 0.0.0.0 -p 8088 --with-threads --reload --debugger` and... I was redirected to the login page again! I checked the console and found a warning: WARNING:root:Class 'werkzeug.local.LocalProxy' is not mapped.

I'm not very experienced with Linux, so at this point, I have no idea what to do next.

Can anyone suggest what to do next?

Comment: this question should be asked here https://askubuntu.com/

Comment: This question is not related to Ubuntu but rather concerns the installation and usage of Superset.

I found the following workaround. TALISMAN_ENABLED=False.

Comment: resolved? I did exactly the same steps and had the same CSRF error, after solving it I had the error "WARNING:root:Class 'werkzeug.local.LocalProxy' is not mapped", but without success in resolving

Comment: Users might be interested in the main discussion of solving this login loop with Superset 3.0.0: https://github.com/apache/superset/issues/24579

@Fabio that WARNING is a warning, not an error, and shouldn't affect Superset's performance.

Answer (score 3):

I found the following workaround: In `/home/superset/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/superset/config.py` set:

```py
TALISMAN_ENABLED=False
```

Comment: This solved my 'WARNING:root:Class 'werkzeug.local.LocalProxy' is not mapped' issue on Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS), I don't think it is safe to do on a prod server but it should be fine for anything non-prod.

Answer (score 1):

This is great - thank you for documenting this.

I installed `pillow` to resolve the errors/warnings about `PIL`

`pip3 install pillow`

I also wanted to share a bit about how I got around the `WTF_CSRF_ENABLED` part of step 21.  This felt weird to me, to be modifying the source for a package... I set the following in my python config file:

```
WTF_CSRF_ENABLED = False
TALISMAN_ENABLED = True

TALISMAN_CONFIG = {
    "content_security_policy": {
        "default-src": ["'self'"],
        "img-src": ["'self'", "data:"],
        "worker-src": ["'self'", "blob:"],
        "connect-src": [
            "'self'",
            "https://api.mapbox.com",
            "https://events.mapbox.com",
        ],
        "object-src": "'none'",
        "style-src": ["'self'", "'unsafe-inline'"],
        "script-src": ["'self'", "'strict-dynamic'"],
    },
    "content_security_policy_nonce_in": ["script-src"],
    "force_https": False,
    "session_cookie_secure": False
}
```

Comment: and resolve other error "WARNING:root:Class 'werkzeug.local.LocalProxy' is not mapped"? :/

Comment: This is great - I wouldn't say you're "modifying the source", this is how you customize a Superset deployment.

Comment: Yea, that's fair.  I did not modify the source, just provided additional configuration :D