# when opening Apache Superset, it keeps loading on the welcome page itself

Tags: apache-superset

After installation superset in python environment try to open superset but after login its keep loading in welcome page itself. In log I am getting

```
2023-10-17 12:22:03,990:INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [17/Oct/2023 12:22:03] "←[32mGET /superset/welcome/ HTTP/1.1←[0m" 302 -
```

I try to fix using below code

```
# Build javascript assets
cd superset-frontend
npm ci
npm run build
```

But I am not able to find superset-frontend folder in my machine.

can anyone help on this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Successful installation of Superset (3.0.0) on Ubuntu 22.04.3, but failed to log in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77258840/successful-installation-of-superset-3-0-0-on-ubuntu-22-04-3-but-failed-to-log)

Comment: No, I tried is not working.